# Format DateTime without converting it to a string in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, datetime, datetime-format

In my app, I need to have a DateTime variable with this format: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" but it should not be a string.

These are the things that I've tried so far:

```
    var now = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var currentTime = DateTime.ParseExact(now, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var currentTime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(now, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    var turkishCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR");
    var currentTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(now, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", turkishCultureInfo);
    var currentTime3 = DateTime.ParseExact(now, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);

    Debug.Log("now: " + now); // 06.01.2023 21:25:27
    Debug.Log("currentTime: " + currentTime); // 1/6/2023 9:25:27 PM
    Debug.Log("currentTime1: " + currentTime1); // 1/6/2023 9:25:27 PM
    Debug.Log("currentTime2: " + currentTime2); // 1/6/2023 9:25:27 PM
    Debug.Log("currentTime3: " + currentTime3); // 1/6/2023 9:25:27 PM
```

As you can see above, I tried ParseExact method with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, turkishCultureInfo and null all have the same output. 1/6/2023 9:25:27 PM, but I need like this 06.01.2023 21:25:27

I don't want to use string because I need to use methods like Subtract, AddSeconds that's why I need a DateTime type variable. Is there a way to get "DateTime.Now" formatted as "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"?

---

The examples above are not my real problem. I just wanted to show what I need but I believe it wasn't that clear. This is my actual problem:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan totalTime = now.Subtract(DateTime.ParseExact(lastTime, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

"lastTime" is a string value retrieved from database with that format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"

But when I try to get TimeSpan between "now" and "lastTime" I get this error:

```
FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] s, System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] format, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style) (at <d6232873609549b8a045fa15811a5bd3>:0)
System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at <d6232873609549b8a045fa15811a5bd3>:0)
```

Comment: A `DateTime` variable has no format.  They are just a number to indicate a point in time.  *Formats* only become apparent when displayed.  Suggested Reading: **[DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a bit of a confusion here what the string concatenation does to your values.

It is nothing less than simply using the **default** format for a parameterless `ToString()`!

Each of your strings like

```
Debug.Log("currentTime: " + currentTime);
```

basically internally implicitly equal

```
Debug.Log("currentTime: " + currentTime.ToString());
```

In that case the `ToString()` without parameters can be omitted since c# already uses it implicitly.

=> You **are** using `string` in all your examples! How else do you think anything is logged (as a string!) to the console? ;)

As noted in the comments a [`DataTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime) is just a point in time and basically just a kind of wrapper around a `long` which are the **system ticks** passed since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

All the other properties, values and formats are calculated based on those ticks on demand (which makes it quite expensive btw).

> Is there a way to get "DateTime.Now" formatted as "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Yes, exactly how you did it.

So what you want to do is just use `DateTime` for all your calculations and `AddMinutes` etc. and then only when you need to **display** the (current) value you simply pass in the correct format just like you did in your first line

```
const string format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

and

```
Debug.Log("currentTime: " + currentTime.ToString(format));
```

---

**Update**

Now finally knowing your actual code and issue

There is no reason to use parse here ... what you want is

```
TimeSpan totalTime = DateTime.Now - lastTime;
```

and then [`Debug.Log(totalTime.ToString(YOUR_DESIRED_FORMAT));`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring#system-timespan-tostring(system-string))

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I believe I wasn't that clear so the post got many downvotes. I updated my post and pasted my error. My problem is not related to displaying the date. I'm trying to get a timespan between 2 dates. One is lastTime string formatted like 06.01.2023 21:25:27 and other one is now which is DateTime.Now and I get the error when I try to do this operation.

Comment: There is no reason to use parse here ... what you want is `var now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan totalTime = now - last time;` and then [`Debug.Log(totalTime.ToString(YOUR_DESIRED_FORMAT));](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring#system-timespan-tostring(system-string))` ..

Answer (score -1):

you can create DateTimeExtensions class, to get string in expected forma easly:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    const string myFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    public static string GetInMyFormat(this DateTime dt)
        => dt.ToString(myFormat);
}
```

and use it:

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-36.23);
Debug.Log("myDateTime in my format: " + DateTime.Now.GetInMyFormat());
```